# Using a loop to make a random sentence generator

Tags: python, random

My Python skills are incredibly basic and that's why you're about to look through a horrible mess.

Basically, I want to use text files to make a list of words. Each file will have its own type of word (Nouns, verbs, etc.). Then I want randomly pick words out of that list and fill them in the appropriate spots in a random sentence template, kind of like Mad Libs. My problem is when I try to fit everything into a loop. I get a random template each time, but I cannot figure out how to make the randomly selected word change every time.

This is the function for reading the file and adding its contents to a list, which seems to work fine.

```
def get_Noun():
    infile = open('Noun.txt', 'r')
    nouns = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    index = 0
    while index < len(nouns):
        nouns[index] = nouns[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1
    Noun = random.choice(nouns)
    return Noun
```

Next are functions for my two sentence templates and a function for randomly selecting one of them:

```
Noun = get_Noun()
Noun2 = get_Noun()
def Cake():
    get_Noun()
    print("The", Noun, "is a", Noun2)

def XistheNew():
    get_Noun()
    print(Noun, "is the new", Noun2)

def get_Sentence():
    num = random.randrange(1, 3)
    if num == 1:
        Cake()
    elif num == 2:
        XistheNew()
```

Lastly, I have a loop that controls the whole thing. I thought about putting it into another "main" function, but that didn't seem to make a difference anyway.

```
while sp == '':
    get_Sentence()
    sp = input('')
```

What I want to happen is for a new sentence with completely new words to pop up every time I hit enter.

This is an example of the output if I run the loop four times:

> yak is the new frog
>
> yak is the new frog
>
> The yak is a frog
>
> yak is the new frog

The sentence that is chosen seems to be random, but the words do not change. How can I fix this? I know my code is horribly chaotic and somewhat idiotic, but I plan to fix it up once I can get this one thing to work. I really appreciate any help. And like I said, I'm a complete noob so simple answers are appreciated if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to all the answers provided I'd like to point out in your case you would change the code to

```
def Cake():
    print("The", get_noun(), "is a", get_noun())

def XistheNew():
    print(get_noun(), "is the new", get_noun())

def get_Sentence():
    num = random.randrange(1, 3)
    if num == 1:
        Cake()
    elif num == 2:
        XistheNew()
```

This way when `Cake()` or `XistheNew()` is called a new noun is created from your method `get_noun()`

NOTE: I changed your noun varible to lowercase. Like what Vikram linked, there is a convention to python coding style.

Building on what Julien said you would add another method to load the file

```
nouns = load_nouns()

def load_nouns():
    infile = open('Noun.txt', 'r')
    nouns = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    return nouns

def get_noun():
    index = 0
    while index < len(nouns):
        nouns[index] = nouns[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1
    noun = random.choice(nouns)
    return noun
```

This way your file isn't loading every time you call `get_noun()` so your full file would look something like this

```
nouns = load_nouns()

def load_nouns():
    infile = open('Noun.txt', 'r')
    nouns = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    return nouns

def get_noun():
    index = 0
    while index < len(nouns):
        nouns[index] = nouns[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1
    noun = random.choice(nouns)
    return noun

def Cake():
    print("The", get_noun(), "is a", get_noun())

def XistheNew():
    print(get_noun(), "is the new", get_noun())

def get_Sentence():
    num = random.randrange(1, 3)
    if num == 1:
        Cake()
    elif num == 2:
        XistheNew()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are only assigning `noun` and `noun2` once on program initialisation

Try having a new function like so:

```
def set_nouns():
    noun = get_noun()
    noun2 = get_noun()
```

and then call `set_nouns()` instead of `get_noun()` in your `Cake()` and `XistheNew()` functions.

Also, have a read through the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Vikram's answer:

your get_noun function relaods your whole file every time, which is a waste.
Consider having a function that loads your words (only once) to a list and then a function that chooses at random from that list.

Finally: replace all Noun and Noun2 by choose_noun().

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Vikram's (correct) answer, the issue is these lines:

```
Noun = get_Noun()
Noun2 = get_Noun()
```

They create two variables, `Noun` and `Noun2`, then run `get_Noun` twice and assign the results to those variables.

Then, in the line:

```
print("The", Noun, "is a", Noun2)
```

...You aren't rerunning `get_Noun`. Here, `Noun` and `Noun2` are references to the two strings created previously, *not* to the `get_Noun` method. At this point, the program doesn't care how you initially created those variables, it just re-uses their values.

To make the `get_Noun` function run again, you have to explicitly call it again each time, e.g. as in Vikram's answer. To illustrate the point, this would also work:

```
print("The", get_Noun(), "is a", get_Noun())
```

That line *calls the function* everywhere a new random value is needed.